# iOS keep notification badge counter

Tags: ios, swift3, apple-push-notifications

I have notifications working in iOS with a notification feed. I want users to mark messages as read in order for the badge counter to reset back to 0. However, when they close the app, the badge goes away. As soon as they receive another notification the badge counter goes up to whatever the number should have been. For example, if I have 10 notifications and I mark one as read then my badge should stay at 9. But it goes away completely. If I receive another notification then it will go back to 10. Is there a way that I can keep the app from not clearing the badge on app close?

I store all notifications in an sql database, so the badge number is calculated server-side and sent with the notification payload.
This is my app delegate file.

```
import UIKit
import UserNotifications

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        //Request notifications
        // iOS 10 support
        if #available(iOS 10, *) {
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options:[.badge, .alert, .sound]){ (granted, error) in }
            application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        }/*else if #available(iOS 9, *) {
            UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.badge, .sound, .alert], categories: nil))
            UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        }else if #available(iOS 8, *) {
            UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.badge, .sound, .alert], categories: nil))
            UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        }else {  
            application.registerForRemoteNotifications(matching: [.badge, .sound, .alert])
        }*/
        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
        print("Became active")
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }

    // Called when APNs has assigned the device a unique token
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        // Convert token to string
        let deviceTokenString = deviceToken.reduce("", {$0 + String(format: "%02X", $1)})

        // Print it to console
        print("APNs device token: \(deviceTokenString)")
        print(Keychain.set(deviceTokenString, forKey: "device_token"))
        if(Keychain.value(forKey: "user_id") != nil && Keychain.value(forKey: "device_token") != nil){
            // send data to the server
            let requestUrl = NSURL(string: "https://api.website.com/insert_ios_notification_token.php?user_id=\(Keychain.value(forKey: "user_id")!)&email=\(Keychain.value(forKey: "email")!)&password=\(Keychain.value(forKey: "password")!)&token=\(Keychain.value(forKey: "device_token")!)")
            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: requestUrl! as URL)

            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { data, response, error in
                guard let _ = data, error == nil else {
                    print("error=\(error)")
                    return
                }

                if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {
                    print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                    print("response = \(response!)")
                }

            }
            task.resume()
        }

        // Persist it in your backend in case it's new
    }

    // Called when APNs failed to register the device for push notifications
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        // Print the error to console (you should alert the user that registration failed)
        print("APNs registration failed: \(error)")
    }

    // Push notification received
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification data: [AnyHashable : Any]) {
        // Print notification payload data
        print("Push notification received: \(data)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the relevant code.

Comment: @PrerakSola And what would that be? App delegate file?

Comment: The file that handles the incoming notifications.

Comment: Sounds like you are changing the badge yourself rather than using the relevant push notification field ["Badge": Int]

Comment: @SeanLintern88 I calculate the badge number server-side and send it with badge: whatever.

Comment: Ah ok so on the server are you sending 0 ? Maybe as a response to an API call or somethign? Otherwise are you sure you havent copied some code into the app delegate thats sets it to 0 ?

Comment: I never set the value to 0. I doubt handle decrementing the counter yet because I can't keep it shown yet. The database would also never set it to 0 because if it sends a notification then they have at least 1 unread notification.

Comment: try like this `func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    // Convert token to string
    let deviceTokenString = deviceToken.reduce("", {$0 + String(format: "%02X", $1)})
    print("APNs device token: \(deviceTokenString)")
    // Note where are you using deviceTokenString ???`

Comment: `if let userID = Keychain.value(forKey: "user_id"),
        let email = Keychain.value(forKey: "email"),
        let password = Keychain.value(forKey: "password"),
        let device_token = Keychain.value(forKey: "device_token"),
        let url = URL(string: "https://api.website.com/insert_ios_notification_token.php?user_id=\(userID))&email=\(email)&password=\(password)&token=\(device_token)") {
`

Comment: `URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            guard let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode == 200,
                let data = data, error == nil else {
                return
            }
            print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8))
        }.resume()
    }
}`

Comment: @LeoDabus Well I put the deviceTokenString in the keychain and also sent it to my database... I'm not sure what your comments were really suggesting.

Comment: My comment is to first get all your url elements before creating your url String interpolation. I broke it into 3 comments because of the comment size limit